# What is miner_tx_hash?

Tags: monerod, daemon, transaction-data, rpc

I am trying to figure out the Daemon RPC API.

Requesting a block with `get_block()`, the block header has a field `miner_tx_hash`.

The block also contains a JSON field `miner_tx`, which contains the coinbase transaction input "gen" and a single matching output. This I understand.

If I use `get_transactions()` with the value of `miner_tx_hash`, it seems to find a transaction, but this transaction seems quite different from `miner_tx` embedded in the block. The one I get from `get_transactions()` has many more inputs and outputs etc.

Also, I thought there would be a single `miner_tx_hash` value in a block, but there seem to be multiple.

Currently, there is no mention of `miner_tx_hash` as a field in any of the methods in the [API docs](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_last_block_header). If you search the page, some example outputs contain it but no explanation.

So what exactly the `miner_tx_hash` field in the block, and what is its relation to the `miner_tx` and other transactions in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what exactly the miner_tx_hash field in the block, and what is its relation to the miner_tx and other transactions in the block?

`miner_tx_hash` is just that - the transaction *hash* of the miner transaction. The miner transaction is the transaction that pays out the reward for mining the block. The inputs to this tx are type `gen` as they literally generate new Monero.

> If I use get_transactions() with the value of miner_tx_hash, it seems to find a transaction, but this transaction seems quite different from miner_tx embedded in the block. The one I get from get_transactions() has many more inputs and outputs etc.

Perhaps you are calling or parsing incorrectly. Here is a concrete example using testnet:

```
curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block","params":{"height":1234567}}' \
  http://localhost:28081/json_rpc \
  | jq .result.block_header.miner_tx_hash
```

Extracts the miner tx hash: `c37d119798660baed9ee62b3fc7323f98487b2e9c6a155be843e238e31fdb415`

And:

```
curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_block","params":{"height":1234567}}' \
  http://localhost:28081/json_rpc \
  | jq .result.json | jq -r | jq .miner_tx
```

Will extract the miner tx (form the same result, `get_block` with height `1234567`):

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "unlock_time": 1234627,
  "vin": [
    {
      "gen": {
        "height": 1234567
      }
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "amount": 6059550665332,
      "target": {
        "key": "81fb44f0bbd9e38e467461aed50ded48f2301ee0b0d553a1d0bc5a8a07cd0263"
      }
    }
  ],
  "extra": [
    1, ..., 78
  ],
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 0
  }
}
```

Now using `get_transactions` with the miner tx hash obtained above:

```
curl -d '{"txs_hashes":["c37d119798660baed9ee62b3fc7323f98487b2e9c6a155be843e238e31fdb415"],"decode_as_json":true}' \
  http://localhost:28081/get_transactions \
  | jq .txs[0].as_json | jq -r
```

Yields:

```
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 1234627, 
  "vin": [ {
      "gen": {
        "height": 1234567
      }
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [ {
      "amount": 6059550665332, 
      "target": {
        "key": "81fb44f0bbd9e38e467461aed50ded48f2301ee0b0d553a1d0bc5a8a07cd0263"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "extra": [ 1, ..., 78
  ], 
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 0
  }
}
```

Identical.

Comment: Thanks, I see you are correct. I guess I got confused somewhere along going through all the txs, txouts, etc. There is only one miner_tx_hash and the rest are in tx_hashes. And the miner hash matches if queried as you say. There is some difference in the early coinbase transactions containing multiple vout and the current ones seem to only have one. Maybe I got confused about that. Is that change from obfuscating the amounts?